# Calculate limit in use of integrals

Tags: integration, limits, summation

Calculate limit in use of integrals

$$ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1+n}{3k^2+n^2} $$

### My attempt:

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1+n}{3k^2+n^2} = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{\frac{1}{n}+1}{3(k/n)^2+1} = \\
\frac{1}{n}\cdot (1/n + 1) \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{3(k/n)^2+1}  $$
Ok, I know that when I am taking limit I should replace (from aproximation theorem)
$$ \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{3(k/n)^2+1}$$
with 
$$ \int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{1+3x^2}$$
but I still don't know what have I do (and why) with
$$ \frac{1}{n}\cdot (1/n + 1) $$
part. In many solutions we just ignore part $\frac{1}{n}$ but I don't know why and there where I have little more 'difficult' expression like $ \frac{1}{n}\cdot (1/n + 1) $ I completely don't know what should I do...
$$  $$

Comment: The Riemann Sum formula gives you $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{1+3\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)^2}=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{1+3x^2}$. Don't forget the $\frac{1}{n}$. So it just leaves the $1+\frac{1}{n}$.  Can you notice anything about it ?

Comment: Limit of that is going to $1$

Comment: Now, You have the answer

Comment: Exactly, so you have a product of something that converges towards $\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{1+3x^2}dx$ and something that converges towards 1.

Comment: So the part $\frac{1}{n}$ before integral is just because $\frac{b-a}{n} $? It is just size of intervals?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\frac{1}{n}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)\sum...=\underbrace{\frac{1}{n}\sum...}_{\to \int...}+\underbrace{\frac{1}{n}\underbrace{\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{}...\right)}_{\to \int...}}_{\to 0}\to \int...$$

Answer (score 0):

Just ignore the $1$ in the numerator as it is obviously less than $\infty$.

And put $\frac{1}{n}=dx$ & $\frac{k}{n}=x$

So your integration becomes $$\int_0^1\frac{dx}{3x^2+1}=\frac{tan^{-1}\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{3}}$$

Answer to your question, what to do with $\frac{1}{n}(\frac{1}{n}+1)$ as $(\frac{1}{n}+1)\to1$ as $n\to\infty$.

Remember, when factors are in multiplication, partial limit can be applied.

Hope this will be helpful!